# 2D array of char pointers --> Segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, segmentation-fault, new-operator

I have to create a 2-Dimensional array of char pointers. The array will store a list of names and surnames - row 0 will hold names and row 1 will hold surnames. This is the code I have written so far (this file is included in the main file):

```
#include "myFunction.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char ***persons;

void createArray(int n)
{
   *persons = new char * int[n];
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
      *persons[i]=new char[n];
}
```

and main calls this function with:

```
createArray(3);
```

but when I run it i keep getting "Segmentation Fault" and I have no idea why

How can I fix this?

Comment: *persons is going to cause the first segv.

Comment: You are creating a pointer to a two-dimensional array of chars, something entirely different from a two-dimensional array of char pointers (really!). Which do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using c++, consider using a 2D array of std::string as it'll be a little cleaner. Also, multi-dimensional arrays are always horrible to work with as they make code unreadable and cause a lot of chaos (as you don't often get confused by which dimension represents what). So, I strongly urge you to consider using a struct for each person (with 2 fields, first_name and last_name).

Regardless, if you want to go with your approach, here's how you'd do it:

```
char*** people;

int n = 2;  // two elements, name and surname
int m = 5;  // number of people

people = new char**[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  people[i] = new char*[n];
}
```

Comment: oh my word it worked! thank you so much! i've been trying to fix this all day!

Answer (score 0):

Don't make pointers global.
And I am embarassed with this line...

```
*persons = new char * int[n];
```

I don't think that it's right. '*' is extra here. Maybe, it's right?

```
persons = new char * int[n];
```

But I don't know exactly.

Comment: Or even...

persons = new char *[n]

Answer (score 0):

I should comment that instead of a multi-dimensional array, it sounds like you should be using an array of structures, with members for first name and surname.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question!! He asked about segmentation fault not about how should he design it.